# Jetpack Compose align input text in TextField

Tags: user-interface, textfield, user-experience, android-jetpack-compose, text-alignment

I would like to achieve similar behaviour with `TextField` from Jetpack Compose like from old school XML layout:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/some_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right" /> <!-- or end -->
```

When I try this approach:

```
TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {

}, textAlign = TextAlign.End)
```

It simply just doesn't work because `textAlign` property doesn't exists in `TextField`. Then how to do input text alignment like `TextAlign.Center`, `TextAlign.End`, `TextAlign.Justify` and so on for `TextField`?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can do it through `textStyle`.

```
TextField(
    value = "",
    onValueChange = {

    },
    textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(textAlign = TextAlign.End)
)
```

`LocalTextStyle.current` is the default value for `TextField`, you can replace it by your own.

Comment: Thanks, then why `textStyle` doesn't exist for `Text` and `textAlign` doesn't exist for `TextField`?

Comment: In `Text` it's called `style`. I'm not sure why such design is taken, probably because changing align for `TextField` is not needed that often. You can set `textAlign` for `Text` the same way as for `TextField`, but it also has `textAlign` that'll override the style value.